# Get position of a word from the index of the first letter of the word

Tags: perl

Suppose I have a sentence/paragraph:

```
This cat is very cute.
```

Here, "cute" is the 5th word in the sentence. If I know the index of the first letter of this word - in this case `c`, 17 - how can I find out the position of this word in the sentence?

Comment: Is any other linux command ok for you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counting the number of spaces in the substring and then adding 1 to it would probably work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $in = "This cat is very cute.";
my $sub = substr $in, 0, 17;

my $word_count = scalar(split " ", $sub) + 1;
print "$word_count\n";
```

Comment: Splitting just by `" "` might be a little restrictive. I would suggest `/\W+/` to include everything that is not alphanumeric or a "connector-punctuation" or at least use `/\s+/` to split only once at any number of spaces or tabs in succession.

Comment: @DeVadder `" "` is a special case: [In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were `/\s+/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Comment: Oh, that would have saved me a few checks for empty strings. Thank you.